# How to add and remove input tag according to the given number of item in angular 9?

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I have a data form database like this,
`

```
{
 noOfChildren : 2,
 childAge:[4,5]
}
```

`

I am trying to code to edit page these thing.

```
<div class="form-group">
                      <label for="flightChild" class="label">No of Children in Flight (2YRS - 17YRS)
                      </label>
                      <input type="number" min="0" max="9" nbInput fullWidth id="flightChild" placeholder="No of Children in Flight"
                        formControlName="flightChild" 
                        (keyup)="onNoOfChild($event)"/>
    </div>


   <div *ngIf="noOfChild > 0"  class="row" >
                  <div id="flightChildAge" class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="flightChildAge" class="label">Children's age
                      </label>
                      <input type="number" min="3" max="17"  nbInput fullWidth id="flightChildAge" placeholder="Children's age"
                        formControlName="flightChildAge" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
     </div>
```

**I have tried this code. BUT I NEED TO MODIFY

If noOFChild =1, then no of input tag for child's age = 1.

If noOFChild =2, then no of input tag for child's age = 2.

If noOFChild =1, then no of input tag for child's age = 3.

If noOFChild =1, then no of input tag for child's age = 4. and so on..**

How to do this in angular?

Comment: Better post with stackblitz example.

Answer (score 1):

For step by step instructions check https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms

Briefly:

```
youeForm = this.fb.group({
  noOfChildren : [1, Validators.required],
  flightChildAge: this.fb.array([])
});

for (let index = 0; index < this.model.noOfChildren; index++) {
      this.flightChildAges.push(this.fb.control(0));
}
```

this is the getter for child ages control

```
get flightChildAges() {
  return this.youeForm.get('flightChildAge') as FormArray;
}
```

Your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let child of flightChildAges.controls; let i=index">
    <label for="child-{{ i }}">Children's age:</label>
    <input id="child-{{ i }}" type="text" [formControlName]="i">
  </div>
```

You assign the index to the **i** variable and pass it to each control to bind it to the formControlName input.

Comment: Hi, this.fb.control(0) it means noOfChildren?  or what?

Comment: No, this means we are adding a new formControl (for the new input - child age input - in the template) and we are giving it a default value = 0. You can pass any default value or keep it empty.

Comment: Okay Okay Thank you